# Mac OS Web Sharing - where are the apache logs?

Tags: mac-osx

I've got web sharing enabled (System Preferences / Sharing / Web Sharing ) on my mac os x machine (10.6).  I'd like to inspect the apache logs to look at the user agent string.  Where are these logs kept?  Answers on here appear to suggest /var/log/httpd, but there's nothing there on my machine.

Anyone know where they are?

Thanks!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try /private/var/log/apache2
Also, this path is hidden to the finder, so you will either need to use Terminal.app (in utilities) to get to it, or use "Go to Folder" from the Finder menu.

Comment: The easiest way to get to that location and read the files would be to run Utilities -> Console.  Under 10.5, you can adjust disclosure triangles to get to LOG FILES -> /var/log -> apache2.  (I suspect it is the same or very close under 10.6).